# How to find out which image in an has my variable been assigned to?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of images;

```
var imageArray = new Array();       
imageArray[0] = new Image();
imageArray[0].src = "first.png";
imageArray[0].id = "first";
imageArray[1] = new Image();
imageArray[1].src = "second.png";
imageArray[1].id = "second";
```

and it is randomly assigned to a variable by :

```
var hobby = new Bitmap( imageArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArray.length)]);
hobby.onPress= alerting();
```

What I am trying to do is create an alert when each image is clicked. I want the alert to be the image id. The following is what I tried to do but it didn't work. What I'm I doing wrong. Is there better way of doing this rather than if statements?

```
function alerting(){
    if (hobby = imageArray[0]){
        alert("first")
    }
    else {
        alert("second")
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any image ids.  When you say "didn't work", what did you expect, and what happened instead?

Comment: For one thing, use == inside of an if, not single =.

Comment: `if (hobby = imageArray[0])` is not a comparison, it's an assignment

Comment: Use `==` instead of `=` in your if statement

Comment: when i wrote 'imageArray[0].id = "first" 
I was trying to give it an id. Isn't that right? @ScottHunter

Answer (score 0):

You can store the random image in a variable before passing it to the `Bitmap` constructor, and then access its `id`:

```js
var rndImage = imageArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArray.length)],
    hobby = new Bitmap(rndImage);
// ...
alert(rndImage.id);
```